# node.js net.connect() error in spite of try-catch

Tags: javascript

This code is producing an error in spite of a try-catch block... It should send a error message, if the server isn't reachable and a positive message, if ist is.

```js
try {
  net.connect(25565, "mc.hypixel.net", () => {
    console.log("connected");
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log("not connected");
}
```

This is the error:

```sh
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.78.21:25565
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '104.16.78.21',
  port: 25565
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: btw if i have the correct answer pls mark :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hmm.. I believe the following answer is what [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error) suggests

**try this**

```js
net.connect(25565, "mc.hypixel.net", () => {
  console.log("connected");
})
.on('error', (err)=>console.log("not connected"));
```

Comment: yea, 2 days ago i faced something similar with websockets in `ws` and catching the error required a different approach.. it's strange ;-;

Comment: it's asynchronous. Try/catch won't do anything because it has continued beyond the try/catch by the time the error occurs